# v$version still showing 9i in sql developer after upgrade to 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was working on Oracle 9i. I got it upgraded to 10g  3 hr. back. But when I query v$version to check the version in SQL Developer, it shows Oracle 9i.

Could you please let me know if I need to modify any settings in the SQL Developer tool to reflect the upgraded version?

Thanks,
Savitha

Comment: v$version probably does not lie. Do you have any other indication that the upgrade was completed successfully?

Comment: @Thilo: Yes. When I connect as SYSDBA on SQL* PLUS and query the same, it says Oracle 10g Express Edition.

Comment: That's good. ;-) Are you sure you are connecting to the right DB in SQL Developer?

Comment: Are you sure you can upgrade an Oracle 9 instance with the _Express_ _Edition_? Are you sure you have performed an upgrade and not created a second parallel installation of Oracle?

Comment: @Codo: hmmm.....not sure. Looking at your comment, I think its a parallel installation and not an upgrade. How can I make sure whether its a parallel installation or an upgrade?

Comment: If you had your own data in the Oracle 9i, then you can have a look whether you can find it in the 10g instance with SQL*plus. If it's there, the data has at least been migrated (doesn't rule out a parallel installation). Furthermore, you can query the table DBA_DATA_FILES with SQL*plus and SQL developer. Do they show the same files? (These are the files where your tables are stored.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a client upgrade, you can get the Oracle Home being used by SQL Developer by clicking Help->About->Properties and checking the value for oracle.home.  Usually the name of the Oracle Home will give you an indication of the version of Oracle that you are using.  If not, navigate to the BIN directory in ORACLE HOME and execute sqlplus /nolog.